# uid 1002 has no permission to perform this operation

Tags: 16.04, wireless, permissions

When I am trying to switch to another wifi network. I am getting below error

(1) Private connection already active on the device: uid 1002 has no permission to perform this operation

Refer attached image.

[image]

My machine details:-

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

What is the actual problem here and how to solve this ?

Comment: Let know who or what has the `uid` 1002 with `cat /etc/passwd | grep 1002
`

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | grep 1002
karunakaranpalm:x:1002:1002:KarunakaranPALM,,,:/home/karunakaranpalm:/bin/bash

Comment: I am guessing that's you, so you need to first disconnect the wifi from any previous operations before using it else where.

Comment: @George When I click disconnect option in Wifi. I see same error as  "Connection activation failed" in attached screen-shot

Answer (score 3):

Last time I got this, I was logged in as user A, but another user B on the same machine was logged in at the same time. I logged out from both of them, logged in as A again and then everything worked fine.

---

Alternatively, https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/773 suggests users should be a member of at least one of the `sudo` or the `netdev` groups. To add your current user to `netdev`, simply:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER netdev
```

(See the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/60-network-manager.rules` for the actual test-for-group-membership.)

Answer (score 0):

Above issue is specific to user. I am able to switch wifi networks in other users. I have enabled "All users may connect to this network" option in Networks conneciton and restarted my machine. Now I didn't see the above issue when I switch Wifi network.

[image]